# Animal Storage TreeView - Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, object-oriented, tkinter, gui, graphics

Bit of a pointless program (at the moment). It's intended more as practice for myself rather than anything else.

General idea is that you add details of a  particular cat or dog, and it'll update a TreeView. A dog or cat can then be removed based on their assigned number.

Many thing I wasn't too sure on when creating this, such as best practices for creating a new form, accessing a class's parent attributes, and just general structure.

There's a lot more I want to add here (e.g. filters) - however I worry I'm repeating myself a lot throughout the code, and hardcoding things too much. The more functionality I try to add, the messier it seems to get.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.master = master
        self.my_storage = Storage()

        # Setup Frames.
        self.f1 = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.f2 = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding = (10, 10, 10, 10))
        self.f1.pack(fill = tk.X)
        self.f2.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
        
        # Setup GUI widgets.
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):

        # Setup Tree widget to store animal objects.
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.f2)
        headings = ["Type", "Name", "Breed", "Colour", "Size", "Bark", "Aggression", "Cuteness"]
        self.tree["columns"] = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
        self.tree.column("#0", width = 45)
        self.tree.heading("#0", text = "No.")
        for index in range(len(headings)):
            self.tree.column(index, width = 110)
            self.tree.heading(index, text = headings[index])

        # Setup Buttons and Entry widgets.
        self.position = tk.IntVar()
        self.add_dog = ttk.Button(self.f1, text = "Add Dog", command = lambda: self.add_window("Dog"))
        self.add_cat = ttk.Button(self.f1, text = "Add Cat", command = lambda: self.add_window("Cat"))
        self.remove_animal = ttk.Button(self.f1, text = "Remove by ID", command = self.remove_animal)
        self.remove_animal_pos = ttk.Entry(self.f1, textvariable = self.position, width = 3)

        # Add Widgets to GUI.
        self.add_dog.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        self.add_cat.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        self.remove_animal.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        self.remove_animal_pos.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        self.tree.pack(expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)

    # Remove entry from library based on it's index / No
    def remove_animal(self):
        self.my_storage.remove_animal(self.position.get())
        self.update_tree()

    # Update the tree with the latest version of our storage list.
    def update_tree(self):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
        for i, x in enumerate(self.my_storage.storage):
            obj_type = x.__class__.__name__
            if obj_type == "Dog":
                self.tree.insert("", "end", text = i, values = (obj_type, x.name, x.breed, x.colour, x.size, x.bark_sound, "n/a", "n/a"))
            else:
                self.tree.insert("", "end", text = i, values = (obj_type, x.name, x.breed, x.colour, x.size, "n/a", x.aggression, x.cuteness))

    # Add a new window which allows us to input paramaters for our animal objects.
    def add_window(self, type_of_animal):
        self.window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        AddAnimal(self.window, type_of_animal, self.my_storage, self.tree)
        
class AddAnimal(App):

    def __init__(self, master, type_of_animal, my_storage, my_tree):
        self.tree = my_tree
        self.my_storage = my_storage
        self.master = master
        self.type_of_animal = type_of_animal
        self.widgets()
    
    def widgets(self):
        
        # Set titles depending on type of animal we're adding.
        if self.type_of_animal == "Dog":
            self.titles = ["Name", "Breed", "Colour", "Size", "Bark Sound"]
        else:
            self.titles = ["Name", "Breed", "Colour", "Size", "Aggression", "Cuteness"]
        
        # From titles, create the relevant entry boxes and labels.
        self.entries = {}
        for x in self.titles:
            frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
            frame.pack(side = "top", fill = "x")
            label = tk.Label(frame, width = 20, text = x, anchor = 'w')
            entry = tk.Entry(frame)
            label.pack(side = "left")
            entry.pack(side = "right", expand = True, fill = "x")
            self.entries[x] = entry
    
        self.add_bttn = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Add", command = lambda: self.add_to_tree(self.titles))
        self.add_bttn.pack()
    
    def add_to_tree(self, fields):

        # Store all entry values in list.
        lis = [self.entries[title].get() for title in self.titles]

        # Depending on type of animal, create new animal object with relevant entry values.
        if self.type_of_animal == "Dog":
            name = lis[0]; breed = lis[1]; colour = lis[2]; size = lis[3]; bark_sound = lis[4]; 
            obj = Dog(name, breed, colour, size, bark_sound)
        else:
            name = lis[0]; breed = lis[1]; colour = lis[2]; size = lis[3]; aggression = lis[4]; cuteness = lis[5]
            obj = Cat(name, breed, colour, size, aggression, cuteness)

        # Add object to our strorage list, update the tree with this list, and clos form.
        self.my_storage.add_animal(obj)
        self.update_tree()
        self.master.destroy()

class Storage:
     
    def __init__(self):
         self.storage = []
         
    def add_animal(self, animal):
        self.storage.append(animal)

    def remove_animal(self, position):
        self.storage.pop(position)

class Animal:

    def __init__(self, name, breed, colour, size):
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
        self.colour = colour
        self.size = size

class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, name, breed, colour, size, bark_sound):
        super().__init__(name, breed, colour, size)
        self.bark_sound = bark_sound

class Cat(Animal):

    def __init__(self, name, breed, colour, size, aggression, cuteness):
        super().__init__(name, breed, colour, size)
        self.aggression = aggression
        self.cuteness = cuteness

root = tk.Tk()
App(master = root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: gui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little for the styling of the GUI

## Add an icon to your application

Tkinter has made it very easy to add an icon to any of our windows, it's a single line that makes your GUI look good.

All you need to do is go to a website like [this](https://icon-icons.com/) one and download any `.ico` file of size `16x16`, I haven't tested it with other sizes and formats, but usually, you'll find plenty in this size!

Once you have your `.ico` file, you need to place it in the same directory as your source files.

- Tip: place them in a folder relative to the source files, so you just have to do `images/`, this keeps your project directory clean!

```py
window.iconbitmap("path to your file")
```

That's all there is!

---

## Add a title

This one is even easier, all you need to do is

```py
window.title(" your title " )
```

---

## Avoid unnecessary classes

you have a class `Storage`, but all it really does is hold a list of animals. You don't need to create a new class for this, a simple list in `App` works.

```py
def __init__(...):
    self.animals = []
```

Since you have inherited your `AddAnimal` class from `App`, you can easily add an animal to `self.animals`, It's easier that way

---

## Why is `AddAnimal` a class?

I understand what you are trying to do, but I don't see why `AddAnimal` should be a class

It should just be a function in your `App class`, it is very important that you structure your Tkinter application right otherwise it looks extremely convoluted, let me show you how this program should be structured ( or can be )

First, let's start with the animal structure

[image: animal class]

The good point is, your program follows this perfectly. `Animal` has

- name
- breed
- dog
- size

`Dog` has

- bark sound

`Cat` has

- Agression         <sup>what?</sup>
- Cuteness

It is a good structure, you have re-used `Animal` attributes in `Cat` and `Dog`, but now when you have to have the main application, your program is a little convoluted

****Here is how it can be structured better****

[image: Main]

After this, there won't be a need for extra classes like `Storage` and `AddAnimal`

---

### Animal

```py
f self.type_of_animal == "Dog":
    self.titles = ["Name", "Breed", "Colour", "Size", "Bark Sound"]
else:
    self.titles = ["Name", "Breed", "Colour", "Size", "Aggression", "Cuteness"]
```

These **don't** belong to `AddAnimal`, these should be a part of your `Animal` class since these are attributes of `Animal`, so your class misses one thing

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, breed, colour, size):
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
        self.colour = colour
        self.size = size
        self.all_attributes = [self.name, self.breed, self.colour, self.size]

class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, name, breed, colour, size, bark_sound):
        super().__init__(name, breed, colour, size)
        self.bark_sound = bark_sound
        self.all_attributes.append(self.bark_sound)

class Cat(Animal):

    def __init__(self, name, breed, colour, size, aggression, cuteness):
        super().__init__(name, breed, colour, size)
        self.aggression = aggression
        self.cuteness = cuteness
        self.all_attributes.append(aggression)
        self.all_attributes.append(cuteness)
```

This way when you create a new animal, you already have its `titles`.

```py
my_cat = Cat("milo","turkish","brown","small",aggression = "0",cuteness = "100")
print(my_cat.all_attributes)
```

> ['milo', 'turkish', 'brown', 'small', '0', '100']

---

### App

As I said, `App` should hold a list of `Animal` objects, so everytime you need to add a new animal, it's extremely simple

```py
class App:
    def new_cat():
        # get all input through the GUI widgets 
        self.animals.append( Cat(attributes...) )
    def new_dog():
        self.animals.append( Dog(attributes...) )
```

<sup>It is heavily nerfed to show only the important stuff, other Tk stuff remains</sup>

---

## Avoid Magic Numbers

```py
name = lis[0]; breed = lis[1]; colour = lis[2]; size = lis[3]; bark_sound = lis[4];
```

All are [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), an [enum](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/enum-in-python#:%7E:text=Enum%20is%20a%20class%20in,enum%20has%20the%20following%20characteristics.) would be perfect here

```py
from enum import Enum

class Columns(Enum):
    name = 0
    breed = 1
    ...
```

Since the values change for `Cat` and `Dog` , the `Enum` can be a part of the respective class so there isn't any problem

---

## Nitpicks

- There still are many magic constants in your program like width, padding, etc

```py
headings = ["Type", "Name", "Breed", "Colour", "Size", "Bark", "Aggression", "Cuteness"]
self.tree["columns"] = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

I think you should change this to

```py
self.headings = ("Type", "Name", "Breed", "Colour", "Size", "Bark", "Aggression", "Cuteness")
self.tree["columns"] = self.headings
```

Since `headings` is a part of our `App` , it should be a member

- After adding a record to the tree, the details don't seem to be centered with the column heading, you should use `anchor` to center them

Comment: Thanks! First I'm hearing from Enum's. I'm not sure this would definitely work - as the number's change depending on whether it's a `Cat` or `Dog` object (e.g. 4 equals aggression in cats and bark sound for dogs). Regarding the `AddAnimal` class. I read somewhere that new windows should be a separate class - but this may have been wrong. For the `Storage` class, I kept this has a class as I planned on having extra functionality associated with it (e.g. filters). Adding the `all_attributes` attribute makes a lot of sense. I hadn't thought of this!

Comment: @AaronWright Yes, you can keep then enum as a part of the `Cat` or `Animal` class, that way there isn't any confusion, I'll add that to my answer

Comment: Perekh Thanks for that. Regarding the `AddAnimal` class - how would I structure this if it wasn't a class? As in, should the `widgets` method under this class remain as a method, along with the 'add_window' method in the `MainApp` class. The only way I've been shown regarding the creation of new windows, is to add them as their own class.

Comment: @AaronWright [Join this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115566/tkinter-discussion) We can discuss here

Comment: Thanks Aryan! I'm at work right now, but I'll join the chat room tonight once I'm finished.

Answer (score 0):

It is often good practice to put the main program controller in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` so that in case you would want to import this program in another file you would not open the window up immediately, only if you run this file directly. In your case, that controller would be the last three lines:

```py
...
        self.aggression = aggression
        self.cuteness = cuteness

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(master = root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll add this in. I was always a bit confused as to what was meant by `if __name__ == "__main__"`

Comment: @AaronWright no problem! [here's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) the official documentation on it

Comment: It is like the `main()` function of python